# Recycle bin fills with temp files

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, recycle-bin, temporary-files

I have windows 10 pro installed in my PC. My recycle bin has started to fill up with a same-named file called, tempOTAupdate. Despite I delete them over and over, they keep filling the bin. Windows update has been turned off, if that counts. Please help..
Thanks in advance

Comment: OTA may mean "Over-The-Air". See does some software installed uses OTA? try to disable its autoupdate...

Comment: windows does not use OTA terms for updating. Possibly a phone or tablet doing OTA?